# Save date to database in Yii Framework using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, yii

I would like to extend the validity of a given post
I first list all the post and besides each post, I created a button and when I click, I would like to update the existing toDate and add 1 month.

In the following code, when the user click on the extend button,  I display the view of the post by calling the post/update action, it displays the view and the user can update manually the toDate field. How can I update the field directly from Ajax/jquery on success without having to display the update form?

My button contains the following

```
<p><input type ="button" id = "buttonExtend" value="Extend Validity"></p>
```

and my jquery script contains the following

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){                     
      $(function(){
$("#buttonExtend.click(function(e){
            $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('post/update', array('id' => $data['id'])); ?>",
               success: function(data) {
                //$("#extendValidity").html(data).fadeIn(500);


            }
           });
        });
      });
    });
</script>
```

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

I founded,  I have to put the correct format.

Additionally,  I add 1 month to the current date

```
$model->toDate = date('Y-m-d h:i:s a',(strtotime('next month',strtotime(date('Y-01-d')))));
```